Is there an ethics term for adjudicating for the least total violent outrage, at the expense of fairness?
Let's say two people are in a disagreement.  Everyone knows the first is generally peaceable, and even when treated unfairly, will usually take it and move on.  The second is a bully, and whenever he is rebuked, even if he deserves it, he will throw a tantrum, maybe try to sway other people to his cause, perhaps use legal threats, whatever he can to cause a stink.  To me, it seems common for certain leadership to adjudicate the dispute with the aim of causing the least violent overall outrage; which means in this case, siding much closer to the bully than the truth will admit, because everyone knows the peaceable person will probably, in the end, simply take it and move on, and the bully will be (mostly) happy.  And yet, obviously this is at the expense of truth and fairness.
The term "appeasement" seems close, except it's broader in that it doesn't necessarily apply to leadership, and it also doesn't necessarily imply any skewing of the truth; i.e., the proverbial school kid giving the bully his lunch money is appeasement, but that's not what I'm thinking of.  Short-term pragmatism or utilitarianism seem close, but as pointed out in the comments, appeasing bullies can have bad long-term effects.  The term "selfishness" seems too broad.
Does this kind of adjudication have a specific name in ethics?  (To be clear, I disagree with this method of leadership, I've just noticed it over the years and wondered if it has a name.)

Side note: appeasing bullies would probably have worse consequences or utility in the long run, from people facing no consequences for bullying. Holding people accountable and responsible is one of the main ways to prevent bad behaviour.

"Talk is cheap, until you talk with a Lawyer." One strategy against bullies is to keep suing them until they run out of resources. I'm guessing that courts are sympathetic to that. Lawyers think it is great.

It's not quite like putting a goat in with a rhinoceros, unfortunately.

Just to be clear, I don't agree with this method of adjudication that fears the bully, I've just seen it rather frequently  over the years and wondered whether it had a name.

That leadership had failed, and, having seen what is permitted by it, you should match the bullies tactics.

Where have you seen it over the years? Did it 'work', or stop being used because it backfired?

Neville Chamberlain, Winston Churchill, Adolf Hitler...?

"I hate to be a kicker, I always long for peace, but the wheel that squeaks the loudest, is the one that gets the grease" attribution uncertain. "Kicking" was an idiom for causing disturbances. Linton calls the behavior "squeaky wheel leadership":"If leadership styles had a “default setting,” it would likely be Squeaky Wheel Leadership (SWL). Elected councils are often fixated on how the Squeaky Wheels are going to react to their decisions."

Good quote, thanks @Conifold

Just Joined; funny; author asked for definition. Author gets anecdotal input.
I guess that's supposed to assist in the right road to travel for said definition. Or should we just say label? Or namesake? Adjudication relies upon prosecution. Names to define methods of civil terminology are not like naming a river that has just been discovered. But. Levels of propriety as well as sociology need clarification in such vague (yet repetitive) situations. My take or namesake of the authors query is this.
"The Apex Being and Alpha Dog (or alpha dork) are not compatible. Yet. Are pitted next to each other. Smarts vs Brawn. If the boss or adjudicator sides with Intelligence he will alienate Muscle. Or demote? Why do you think admin tries to be neutral, or aloof?"
They haven't figured out the labels. Or the labels are leveraged - by proxy. Somehow.
To 'name' this situation is to ask for either party to be insulted. That's why it is "NULL!" Lawyers would not even go into such a fray, with such comprehensive ammo.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I am perplexed. Clarity? There are No absolutes "in a point of view" perse. I already "edited" the details. I read and answered. Others read and didn't try to answer.  Clearly - instance is defined. To name such an instance is NOT needed. Since others will argue over etymology.

I believe the reason a Bot commented on your answer, is that the structure of your answer is not as clear to the ones reading it, as it is to the one writing it. To me, it seems like you are, in a very complicated manner, dismissing the question by virtue of a lawyers incentiv to dismiss it. Which is not an answer. There are leaps in your reasoning that can be followed, but leaves the reader to either be charitable or uncharitable with their interpretation of these leaps, which generates the automatic Bot response to your answer.
